# Twitter time to local time c#

Tags: c#, timezone

How do i convert the time of tweets made by the user to localtime? The created_at gives me the time of the tweet created and is based on the user's country, how to i change it to my localtime using c#. The format of the time is "Fri Jul 27 15:14:11 +0000 2012". What do they mean by utc_offset and how can it be used to change the timezone?

I am not really familiar with the timezone stuff, thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to use the [`DateTimeOffset` structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341783).  This allows you to capture a date and a time as well as offset from UTC as well.

The format that you want to use for Twitter times is:

```
string twitterDate = "Fri Jul 27 15:14:11 +0000 2012";

DateTimeOffset dt = DateTimeOffset.ParseExact(twitterDate, 
    "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Note that [while not documented, `zzzz` *does* work as a custom date time format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4) and succeeds in parsing the offset correctly.  This means you should be careful in relying on it in the future (unless the documentation changes to reflect this functionality).

Once you have the `DateTimeOffset`, you know the offset from UTC.  If you want to get it in *your* local time, you can call the [`ToLocalTime` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset.tolocaltime.aspx) on the `DateTimeOffset` that was parsed and it will return an instance that has an offset based on your local settings.

Answer (score 1):

This should be it:

```
DateTime localDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy", new CultureInfo("en-US"));
```

Unless you give a DateTimeKind in the constructor of a DateTime, the DateTime will be in the timezone the administrator of the workstation/server has selected for Windows.

Comment: [`zzzz` is not a supported custom date format.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4)

Comment: Interesting, it's undocumented then.

Comment: I guess it works when parsing, probably wouldn't work if you used it in a ToString call as part of the format string.